# Uppercase FROM causes error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have an sql query that is already written, but the from command is lowercase. I like the formatting of it being uppercase but if I change it I get error 1064.

select, where, and etc were all lowercase as well but when I change to upper they work fine, it is only the WHERE statement that causes this.

Here is the sql:

```
 $listing_sql = "SELECT " . $select_column_list . 
                        "p.products_id, p.products_model, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, " .
                        "p.products_tax_class_id, IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as " .
                        "specials_new_products_price, IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, " .
                        "p.products_price) as final_price ". 
                        "FROM " . 
                        TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p left join " . 
                        TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id left join " . 
                        TABLE_SPECIALS . " s on p.products_id = s.products_id, " . 
                        TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " p2c WHERE p.products_status = '1' AND " .
                        "p.products_id = p2c.products_id and pd.products_id = p2c.products_id and " .
                        "pd.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and p2c.categories_id = '" . 
                        (int)$current_category_id . "'";
```

Here is what the sql looks like when echo'd:

```
SELECT p.products_image,
       pd.products_name,
       p.products_id,
       p.products_model,
       p.manufacturers_id,
       p.products_price,
       p.products_tax_class_id,
       IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL)             AS
       specials_new_products_price,
       IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS
       final_price
FROM   products_description pd,
       products p
       LEFT JOIN manufacturers m
              ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id
       LEFT JOIN specials s
              ON p.products_id = s.products_id,
       products_to_categories p2c
WHERE  p.products_status = '1'
       AND p.products_id = p2c.products_id
       AND pd.products_id = p2c.products_id
       AND pd.language_id = '1'
       AND p2c.categories_id = '36'
```

Comment: have you tried printing out your query and checking the syntax?

Comment: Please post the actual SQL instead (the one that the SQL server sees)

Comment: Can you echo the value of `$listing_sql`? Maybe something is wrong with the variables you are inputting in the string? That's very strange, indeed.

Comment: edited the question to include the echo of the query

Comment: what SQL version are you using?

Comment: Much appreciated. And you say that this query works completely fine with a lowercase "FROM", but will not work as is?

Comment: Should `pd.products_name` be `p.products_name` ?

Comment: There is no syntax error when I run it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1034

Comment: @JoeMajewski yep works perfectly if I use lowercase from. I am using wampserver which says my sql version is 5.5.16

Comment: may I ask why you're using `FROM table, table2 LEFT JOIN table3` syntax? that can easily cause errors.

Comment: I am not the creator of the query, I actually am changing the formatting to only use left join, but ran into this problem while in the process

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Can you post what operating system you're using? I know the case sensitivity with identifiers shifts with the operating system.

Comment: There error is: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: @VoronoiPotato I am using windows 7 home premium 64 bit. I am using wampserver for apache, mysql and php

Comment: have you run this SQL exactly the same as you put in the question edit? noticed you changed it from the original echo dump.

Comment: @jared I beautified the SQL to make it easier to read. Neither version should cause a syntax error.

Comment: "... syntax to use near" - that's it? Nothing afterwards?

Comment: @Esailija for future posting reference how do you beautify the sql on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Sackling I used http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: @deceze here is the entire error sorry about that: 

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT p.products_image, pd.products_name, p.products_id, p.products_model, p.ma' at line 1

Comment: @Sackling to make a `select * from ......` but remove all the selects and try with an asterisks to be sure that the problem is in other place

Comment: Try rearranging the from block to: `FROM products_description pd, products_to_categories p2c, products p LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id LEFT JOIN specials s ON p.products_id = s.products_id` ... though, I agree with @jared 's comment

Comment: for the sql i can assume is osccomerce 2.2, isn't it? the echo of the sql is before the include of the module "product_listing" or in the product listing module?

Comment: Why is there concatenation operator between  = '1' AND " .
                        "p.products_id

Answer (score 1):

An (educated) guess is that you are talking about an OsCommerce instalation.

If that is not the case, you may be using something that once was forked off of it (or its predesessor, *tep*).

The issue you are having may be because the constructor in the  `splitPageResults` class uses `strpos`, which is case sensitive, instead of `stripos`, which is case insensitive.

So... the long and short of it is,

If this indeed is oscommerce:

edit both split_page_results.php files
(1: /catalog/classes/split_page_results.php , 2: /catalog/admin/classes/split_page_results.php)

and replace strpos with stripos in the constructor.

i.e. change

```
$pos_from = strpos($this->sql_query, ' from', 0);
```

to...

```
$pos_from = stripos($this->sql_query, ' from', 0);
```

If this is not osCommerce, just look for something similar.

php doc for [strpost](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try joining products instead:

```
SELECT p.products_image,
   pd.products_name,
   p.products_id,
   p.products_model,
   p.manufacturers_id,
   p.products_price,
   p.products_tax_class_id,
   IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) AS specials_new_products_price,
   IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS final_price
FROM   products_description pd
   LEFT JOIN manufacturers m
          ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id
   LEFT JOIN specials s
          ON p.products_id = s.products_id,
            products_to_categories p2c
   LEFT JOIN products p ON ( p.products_id = p2c.products_id )
WHERE  p.products_status = '1'
   AND p.products_id = p2c.products_id
   AND pd.products_id = p2c.products_id
   AND pd.language_id = '1'
   AND p2c.categories_id = '36'
```